# Why is my theme's CSS affecting the admin area?

Tags: 7, theming, users

So my conundrum is that my sites front-end theme is affecting the admin area. I thought the concept of having a separate admin theme was to avoid this, but alas this doesn't seem to be the case. I've had a similar problem on a few different sites, any ideas on how to prevent theme css loading when working in the admin area?

Comment: I've never seen that happen before, I would assume the CSS you're referring to is actually coming from a module you have installed, and so is site-wide. When Drupal uses the admin theme it categorically doesn't load your custom theme for the same page request, unless you (or a contrib module etc) have told it to

Comment: @Clive or unless some dev/beta/custom caching or aggregating module messed things up. But that pretty much counts like "coming from a module", in a way.

Comment: Yep, very good point @Mołot